# Recursively adding to a list within a list

Tags: c#, recursion

I want to create a recursive function that will add to the nestedContainer object listed below no matter the length based on a multi-dimensional array. The root will be zero and as long as you work from the root you can add as meany as you want. so `0` will contain `0.0, 0.1, 0.2` and `0.0` will contain `0.0.0, 0.0.1, 0.0.2` and so on. The parent must be created before the child can exist.

```
    public class Container()
    {
         public List<Container> container {get; set;}
         public string containerName {get; set;}
         public string index {get; set;}
    } 

    public class ContainerBuilder()
    {
         //This is the main container that will contain all of the children
         Container nestedContainer = new Container();

         //This method will take in the parent index value and then will add the new container into the parent container list based on the value specified
         public void AddContainer(string parentIndex, string containerName, string index)
         {
              Container container = new Container() 
              {
                 index = index,
                 name = name,
                 container = new List<Container>()
              }

              SetContainer(parentIndex, index, container);
          }

          private void SetContainer(string, parentIndex, string index, Container container)
          {
              //Recurive function that will add the new container in the parent container working its way back from the parent   

             //Get the root container, a starting point to add the children
             var rootContainer = nestedContainer .contains[int.Parse(parentIndex.Split('.')[0])];   
          }
     }
```

Implementation

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.AddContainer("0", "Parent 0", "0"); 
builder.AddContainer("0", "Child of parent", "0.x"); 
builder.AddContainer("0.x", "child of child", "0.x.x"); 
builder.AddContainer("0.x.x", "child of a child of a child", "0.x.x.x");
```

You see the index should be irrelivant as long as the path matches so no matter which way you go about it one can add as many children as you want.

Comment: And in your example, how can one find a parent? "*This method will take in the parent index value and then will add the new container into the parent container list*" - what parent container list?

Comment: Please fix your `""` and `,` , it's hard to read now.

Comment: Im not to sure, that is also why i am struggling with this. I guess you could start at the root container and then work your way down

Comment: @MikeBarnes that's my point, there is no "starting" point in the example, what is `nestedContainer` here? Is that the root container? The example is not very clear...

Comment: the `nestedContainer` is the main container that will hold all nested  children. I really struggled to put my thoughts down here, the root would be the first level of containers within `nestedContainer`, so `nestedContainer.container`

Comment: @MikeBarnes but it's impossible to reach `nestedContainer.container` here because it's a private field, nor call `SetContainer` externally because it's also private.

Comment: could one not call `SetContainer` method within the `ContainerBuilder` class? `SetContainer` should not be accessible in the implementation. `ContainerBuilder` class should handle the adding and manipulation of the `nestedContainer`

Comment: @MikeBarnes yes you can, but from a recursive point of view you will need to be referencing *another* container, of which you would then need to call the same method - in order to do that the `SetContainer` method would need to be public. There are other ways of doing this this but I am trying to use the example code you have provided.

Comment: I don't mind other ways of doing it as long as I can add x amount of children

Answer (score 2):

Each `Container` needs to know its parent.  The top level parent will have parent set to null. Each container will also have a list of `Container`

```
public class Container
{
    private Container _parent = null;

    public Container(Container parent, int index)
    {
        _parent = parent;
        Containers = new List<Container>();
        Index = index;
    }

    public List<Container> Containers { get; set; }
    public string ContainerName { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can recurse in either direction

Edit: Here are a couple of functions to add to `Container` class that I think might get you started:

```
//Returns the path of the this container prepending all parent indeces
public string GetPath()
{
    string ret = "";
    if (_parent != null)
    {
        ret = _parent.GetPath();
        ret += String.Format("{0}.", Index);
    }
    return ret;
}

//Gets a child ensuring all container lists contain enough elements
public Container GetChild(string indexPath)
{
    string[] pathParts = indexPath.Split(new[] { '.' }, 2);
    if (pathParts.Any())
    {
        int index;
        if (int.TryParse(pathParts[0], out index))
        {
            //make sure there's enough containers
            Containers = Enumerable.Range(0, index +1).Select(i => new Container(this,i)).ToList();
            if (pathParts.Count() == 2)
            {
                //more sub children so recursively add...
                return Containers[index].GetChild(pathParts[1]);
            }
            return Containers[index];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Tested with:

```
Container c = new Container(null,0);
Console.WriteLine(c.GetChild("2.2.2").GetPath());
Console.WriteLine(c.Containers[0].GetPath());
Console.WriteLine(c.Containers[1].GetPath());
Console.WriteLine(c.Containers[2].GetPath());
Console.WriteLine(c.Containers[2].Containers[0].GetPath());
Console.WriteLine(c.Containers[2].Containers[1].GetPath());
Console.WriteLine(c.Containers[2].Containers[2].GetPath());
Console.WriteLine(c.Containers[2].Containers[2].Containers[0].GetPath());
Console.WriteLine(c.Containers[2].Containers[2].Containers[1].GetPath());
Console.WriteLine(c.Containers[2].Containers[2].Containers[2].GetPath());
```

Which outputs

```
2.2.2.
0.
1.
2.
2.0.
2.1.
2.2.
2.2.0.
2.2.1.
2.2.2.
```

Just need to remove that last "."